# nagvis & nginx configuration: url redirect without location name

Tags: redirect, nginx, nagios

i'm trying to make nagvis (http://www.nagvis.org/) work with nginx. Unfortunately i can't manage to do it ...

i have already a server with several other location and i wanted to add a new one for nagvis. here is one of my tries :

```
server{
    listen   443 ssl;

    root /apps/www/admin;
    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /apps/ssl/admin.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /apps/ssl/admin.key;


    server_name admin admin.mycompany.fr;

    #auth ldap through pam
    auth_pam        "Admin Zone";
    auth_pam_service_name "admin_nginx";

    location ^~ / {
            index index.php;
            include /apps/etc/nginx/php.conf;

    location ^~ /nagvis {
                root /usr/share/nagvis/share;
                index index.php;
                include /apps/etc/nginx/php.conf;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

   location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
                root /usr/share;
                index index.php;
                include /apps/etc/nginx/php.conf;

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

when i tried "https://admin.soc.mycompany.fr/nagvis/index.php" with this configuration i get :

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2015/06/30 11:14:11 [error] 10568#10568: *185 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nagvis/share/nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.20.0.5, server: admin, request: "GET /nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.mycompany.fr"

==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
172.20.0.5 - lagarjoc [30/Jun/2015:11:14:11 +0200] "GET /nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 56 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36"
```

the first index.php in /usr/share/nagvis/share is a redirect to "/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php". It's working well and being redirect to https://admin.mycompany.fr/nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php

but nginx itself is looking for the file in " /usr/share/nagvis/share/nagvis/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php" instead of
"/usr/share/nagvis/share/frontend/nagvis-js/index.php" (the location is to much).

i hope i was clear enough and that you would be able to help me.

thanks in advance, i'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

well, i found a "hack" to make it work.

i simply added a symbolic link like this :

```
ln -s /usr/share/nagvis/share /usr/share/nagvis/share/nagvis
```

i would have like to know if i could avoid the issue directly through nginx configuration but at least this work find for the moment!

hope it will help someone too.